# Getting "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost" despite having SSL enabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, visual-studio-2017

Am creating a ASP.NET Web Application with `Identity` using the `Individual User Account` method of authentication in ASP.NET Core:

[image]

When I run the app, I get the error message in my browser:

> Unable to connect: 
>      Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:44330.
>      ...

In my search for a solution, I found that having SSL disabled could cause this but that was enabled by default.

I have also added:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});
```

to the `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method and added:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToHttps();

        app.UseRewriter(options);
```

to the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` method

Other things I tried based on information I got searching for a solution

- I have also installed `URL Rewrite`
- Tried different browsers
- Checked that my browsers are permitted to go past firewall

All with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trials and errors, I was able to get my web app running on Chrome by following these steps:

**For Chrome**

1. Copy and past `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` into your browser (Chrome) and hit run
2. In the page that opens, locate `Delete domain security policies` Enter `localhost` into the Domain field and click delete.

[image]

The app now runs on Chrome. I'll update this post as soon as I find a solution that works across all browsers.

I also found that the launch browser url had to match the url specified in the `Enable SSL` checkbox had to match:

[image]

To get here, `Right click on Project -> Properties -> Debug`